# PID output to motor rpm

Tags: control-system, brushless-dc-motor, pid-controller, quad-copter, uav

I am working on my project "Control design for tilt rotor." The UAV has 4 tilt rotors and I am using PID to controller for position and attitude control (outer and inner loop).

```
1 (CW)         2 (CCW)



3 (CCW)        4 (CW)
```

I have developed all sub systems in Simulink.

The place I am struggling right now is..

How to generate motor rpm based on PID output?

I am using T-Motors BLDC motor KV420 and 16" prop. I will use Pixhawk 6C. I have set my PID saturation limit as 1024 to -1024.

Output from control system is tau_z (`z`), tau_roll (`r`), tau_pitch (`p`), tau_yaw (`y`).

The PID values are going into control allocation block.

```
M1 = z + r + p - y; M2 = z - r + p + y  
M3 = z - r - p - y; M4 = z + r - p + y
```

The force and moments are calculated based on rpm and thrust, torque coefficient for the combination.

What kind of block or code should I use to convert the PID output to RPM?

Comment: The PID output is proportional to RPM. Whihc means the PID outputs a number, you then need to mulitply that number by some value unique to your enviroment and set up. There may be way to calculate it, be we would need to know a lot more: layout of rotors, full 3D drawings, detailed weights etc to be able to start that calculation. But it's probably easier just to derieve it by experiments. I'd probably start in a controlled enviroment and map the full range of PID output value to the full range of RPM you can sensibly use and test it.

Comment: thanks, as of now I am sending different pwm signals through Arduino to check the rpm and thrust on my test bench. will it be similar to the PID output or something different is required?